# convert list of dictionaries with values in list to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

How do i convert the below to a dataframe as like the expected output below? Please help. I tried other answers of SO but they were in different format of input.

```
ab = [{'q1':[7,2,6]},{'q2':[1,2,3]}]

import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(ab)
```

Current output:

```
    q1  q2
0   [7, 2, 6]   NaN
1   NaN [1, 2, 3]
```

Expected Output

```
    q1  q2
0   7   1
1   2   2
2   6   3
```

Comment: Reformat so that `ab = {'q1':[7,2,6], 'q2':[1,2,3]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple transformation:

```
ds = {k: v for d in ab for k, v in d.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame(ds)
```

Answer (score 1):

Other options.

Using [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat(map(pd.DataFrame, ab), axis=1)
```

or using [`collections.ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap):

```
from collections import ChainMap
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(ChainMap(*ab)))
```

output:

```
   q1  q2
0   7   1
1   2   2
2   6   3
```